# How to safely configure postgresql data folder with docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

- Is this configuration safe to work with PostgreSQL using docker ?
- Do I need any more configurations to make it safer (eg: `.dockerignore`) ?
- Is theire a risk that volumes work on two way binding and that may cause data loose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the postgres container, so backing up the data folder is enough. Starting a new container is cheap in your situation, the data is what is important.

The there no obvious reason for why the volume won't work, unless you delete the `postgres-data` folder accedentaly.

In summary, by inspecting the compose file, things are normal and safe.

Comment: TY. Do I need to .gitignore postgres-data folder ? Do I need to .dockerignore it ?

Comment: Since the `postgres-data` folder and Dockerfile for web are in the same directory, the data folder will be sent to the deamon when building the image. This is unncessary. It will also be mounted into the web container due to volume `- .:/code`. It might be better to move the `postgres-data` folder to another localtion, something like `../postgres-data`

Comment: TY. I prefere using .dockignore instead, this way I wont need to change my folder structure "flat is better than nester"